# slack unfurling link with attachment blocks included

Tags: python, slack-api, slack-block-kit

So my goal is to include an image, with buttons, in a message. However, the file is not public and files_upload method takes away the functionality of the buttons, issue similar to this https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/issues/411.

While working on the solution to 1. upload the file, 2. unfurl the permalink, I managed to make it work but the output is not what I would like:
[image]

I would like the unfurled link image to appear under the blocks while keeping the blocks in the attachment section. Is this achievable? Also, the only time I can unfurl is to include the link within the test section, can this be changed?
Sourcecode:

```
upload_resp = slack_client.files_upload(
                initial_comment=uploadfiles["initial_comment"],
                file=uploadfiles["file"],
                filename=uploadfiles["filename"],
                filetype=uploadfiles["filetype"],
                title=uploadfiles["title"]
            )

attachments = [
                {
                    "blocks": [
                        {
                            "type": "section",
                            "text": {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Hi !*" ,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "divider"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "section",
                            "text": {
                                "type": "mrkdwn",
                                "text": "*Title*"
                            }
                        }
                        ,{
                            "type": "actions",
                            "block_id": "actionblock",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "button",
                                    "action_id" : "rerun_action",
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "Rerun",
                                        "emoji": True
                                    },
                                    "style": "primary",
                                    "value": "rerun"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "button",
                                    "action_id" : "launch_wizard",
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "Launch Wizard",
                                        "emoji": True
                                    },
                                    "style": "primary",
                                    "value": "launch"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            

resp = slack_client.chat_postMessage(
    channel=message["channel_id"],
    text=upload_resp['file']['permalink'],
    attachments = attachments,
    blocks=[],
    unfurl_links=True,
    unfurl_media=True
    )
```